# Problem with Integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

I would like to solve that problem:

Let say I define $F[x]$ function:

```
F[x_] := Integrate[x^2, x]
```

Then I want to calculate eg. $F[2]$, but *Mathematica* emits an `Integrate::ilim` error ("Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in 2.") and throws me something strange:
$\int 4  d2$. Why it puts "$d2$" instead of "$dx$"? How to solve it, so I can easily use my $F[x]$ function?

We all know that $\int x^2 dx = \frac{x^3}{3}$, so the function $F(x)$ should be equal $F(x)=\frac{x^3}{3}$ and then $F(2) = \frac{2^3}{3}=\frac{8}{3}$ but it's not :/

Comment: What would you expect to get from `Integrate[2^2,2]`?

Comment: One way is `f[y_] := Integrate[x^2, x] /. x :> y` then `f[2]` yields `8/3`.

Comment: You should use [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) instead of [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) in this instance. More information can be found in [Understand the difference between Set (or =) and SetDelayed (or :=)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18487#18487).

Comment: Daniel, I'm just quite new to this, that's why I don't understand many things yet :P
corey979, thanks, that works :)
Edmund, thanks too, I'll read about this :)

Comment: @corey979 That will work but is kind of slow since the integral is performed on each call. I prefer to use `Set` as the integral is performed once at assignment; `f[x_] = Integrate[x^2, x]`.

Comment: @Edmund Memoization should help: `f[y_]:=f[y]=....`

Comment: @corey979 Seems more complicated and memory intensive than just using `Set`.

Comment: @Edmund Agreed. Nevertheless, the OP might learn from searching the documentation what `/.` and `:>` are.

Comment: You might want to pay attention to the error message. It's trying to tell what the problem is. Not that it's easy to understand, but if you learn to understand them, the messages are in fact helpful.  E.g., why you do think `Integrate` is using `2` as a ***variable*** of integration in `F[2]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do the integration first, then use the result of the integration to define the function. That is don like this:

```
Block[{x}, f[x_] = Integrate[x^2, x]];
```

Then

```
Definition[f]
```

> `f[x_] = x^3/3`

and

f[2]

> `8/3`

which is what you expect. The way you defined `F`, the integration expression is held unevaluated until `F` is called. When is `F` is called with 2, then 2 replaces each occurrence the symbol `x` in the integral expression and ***then*** the integral is evaluated. That is,

```
Integrate[x^2, x]
```

becomes

```
Integrate[2^2, 2]
```

You need the learn that difference between [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) ( := ) and [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) ( = ). The difference is both important and useful when defining functions in Mathematica.